# Run application without notification bar

Tags: android, notifications, smartphone, mode, kiosk

I'm making appliaction like kiosk mode. I need start other application from my without notification bar for example chrome. How can I do that without ROOT. I don't want to someone can broke kiosk mode in phone settings.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to create a full Kiosk mode through an app like you want to, for security reasons.

Basically you are completely able to display a fullscreen (read: without notification bar) by using a fullscreen theme for the activity.

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

After that though, you can override what happens when a user presses the BACK button, and get a pseudo-kiosk mode running. If the user has a physical back button or app-switcher you are done though.

TL;DR: Fullscreen theme can remove the notification bar, but you can't make a real "kiosk" mode through an app that is distributable on the play store and/or ROOTless.

Comment: Hi. Check SureLock app in play store. They block notification bar. When you try open notification bar it is automaticlly clos. How they make it?